# Split log file using a column with awk or sed

Tags: bash, logging, awk, sed

I have a log file that looks like this:

```
www.domainone.com FIX 3.3 12.12.123.1
www.domainone.com FIX 3.4 12.12.123.1
www.domainone.com FIX 2.4 12.12.123.1
www.domaintwo.com MAX 1.4 44.15.153.5
www.domaintwo.com MAX 3.2 44.15.153.5
www.domaintwo.com MAX 3.9 44.15.153.5
www.domaintwo.com MAX 12.4 44.15.153.5
www.domainthree.com NAN 3.4 34.45.144.7
www.domainthree.com NAN 2.4 34.45.144.7
www.domainthree.com NAN 3.2 34.45.144.7
www.domainthree.com NAN 3.3 34.45.144.7
www.domainthree.com NAN 1.4 34.45.144.7
```

And I want to run a grep, awk, sed or other bash command/script that will split that log file by the last column, so the result is 3 log files that are named using the IP without the dot.  So, one of them would be 34.45.144.7.log and have

```
www.domainthree.com NAN 3.4 34.45.144.7
www.domainthree.com NAN 2.4 34.45.144.7
www.domainthree.com NAN 3.2 34.45.144.7
www.domainthree.com NAN 3.3 34.45.144.7
www.domainthree.com NAN 1.4 34.45.144.7
```

I was able to sort them and remove some columns from original log with with awk but no idea how to split into files using one column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the IP is always the fourth column, you can just use

```
awk '{ filename=$4".log"; if (prev && (filename != prev)) close(prev); print >>filename; prev=filename }' ips.log
```

or according to @Ed Morton, even better yet

```
awk '{ print >>($4".log"); close($4".log") }' ips.log
```

This prints the whole line into a file composed of the fourth column (IP) + ".log"

This is with Ubuntu 12.04 and GNU awk 3.1.8.

Comment: got awk: syntax error at source line 1, context is {print >>> >$4".log" <<<

Comment: I don't get an error when I remove ">" but then it does not get printed to other file.  Also, as explained, I need 3 files, with all the lines, based on IP.

Comment: @iwek What OS and awk do you use?

Comment: I have a MAC OSX 10.6.8, but I can run Ubuntu if necessary.  More importantly, I need 3 files since there are 3 different IP addresses and each of the files needs to have all the lines, not just IP addresses.

Comment: Actually, your code works, thanks!, in OSX you have to do it like this: awk '{filename = $4".log"; print > filename}' test.log

Comment: @iwek I tested your version with my system and it works here as well. So I updated my answer to have a more general solution. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: No need for a variable, just use string concatenation on the redirection: `awk '{print > ($4".log")}' ips.log`

Comment: I don't have one of those to test on, but it's just plain old awk so it should work anywhere. To put it another way, if that DOESN'T work then your awk is severely broken and you need to get another one as who knows what other basic functionality it may not support or implement incorrectly.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you for that info. I updated my answer accordingly :-)

Comment: If there are many splits, you get the AWK two many open files error, which means that I have use a close command but how can I do that without just getting one line in each split file?

Comment: @iwek You must use append `>>` instead of `>`. See my updated answer. But this will be much slower, since it opens and closes the file for every line now.

Comment: Install GNU awk and you won't get those errors and you will have a much better awk in general in terms of functionality. Alternatively since you're last field unique values appear to be contiguous, go back to your previous solution and just add a close() when the value of that field changes instead of on every line.

Comment: I see you edited it and it's close but I meant `awk '{filename=$4".log"; if (filename != prev) close(prev); print >filename; prev=filename }' ips.log`. As-is it'd fail since it's testing filename against just $4 instead of $4".log".

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for spotting my error, fixed. You should contribute your own answer. It would be faster and more accurate than mine. Anyway, thanks for helping. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> so the result is 3 log files that are named using the IP **without the
>   dot**.

```
awk '{f=$4; gsub(/\./,"",f);print > f".log"}' ips.log
```

Comment: got awk: syntax error at source line 1, context is {f=$4; gsub(/\./,"",f);print > >>> f".log" <<<

Comment: the problem is the ">" inside the awk script.

Comment: thanks for this. it was an OSX bug. But you did forget the global.  In OSX, this worked: awk '{filename = gsub(/\./g,"",$4)".log"; print > filename}' test.log

Comment: It's not necessarily a bug. When you do `print > $4 ".log"` does that mean `(print > $4) ".log"` or `print > ($4 ".log")`? The answer is it's ambiguous so you should parenthesize as you want it. In this case you should write `print > ($4 ".log")`.

Answer (score 1):

At @OlafDietsche's request:

```
awk '{ filename=$4".log"; if (filename != prev) close(prev); print >filename; prev=filename }' ips.log
```

Didn't expect the comments to drag out that long or I'd have done that off the bat!